# will_paginate render page count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate, I'm trying to implement go to page.

However, I seem to be having issues with rendering the page count, currently I have the following

```
<div class="nav-pagination-new">
  <%= will_paginate @contacts, previous_label: h('«'), next_label: h('»')  %>

  <% if @contacts.total_entries > 1 %>
    <label for="go-to-page" class="nav-title">Go to page
      <input type="text" id="go-to-page" class="nav-input form-input-sm" name="page"> / <%= @contacts.total_entries %>
    </label>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I've tried `total_entries` and `length` but obviously these won't get the desired result so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's [`@contacts.total_pages`](https://rdoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/master/WillPaginate/CollectionMethods#total_pages-instance_method) you need.

Comment: Yeah just got that when you answered haha, how would I go about using the page param for the input so the user can go to that page, i.e. `<%= text_field_tag params[:page] %>`